# Is there a way to download mods easily without WinRAR?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Is there a way to download mods without WinRAR? It is quite complicated for me to download even one mod with WinRAR, such as Rei's Minimap Mod and TooManyItems Mod.

Comment: May I know why it's complicated to you? Do you prefer downloading each file one-by-one?

Comment: I might prefer that. Do you mean like, by downloading all the files in the mod one-by-one?

Comment: Technically you could switch to 7zip and never see WinRAR again, but I doubt that is the spirit of the question. On the other hand, I still don't know what does downloading the mod with WinRAR mean and how is it problematic. Modding minecraft by manually downloading single mods will be riddled with harder hurdles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

You need to download directly from mod **author's websites**, those nearly everytime come as JAR files, so all you need is to put them into MODS directory of your installation. You don't need any WINRAR work with them. They are not meant to be extracted by any means.

Try to avoid those unoficial websites with "all mods here". Use Curse, search for official Minecraft Forum thread of that mod or official author's page.

---

EDIT:

If you had in mind that you need to open minecraft.jar with WinRAR and drop mod files into it, you should know this is **not needed anymore** and it is **strongly discouraged**. By any means, you should keep minecraft.jar untouched. It was a thing years before, but for new versions you just need to use [Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net) or similar (LiteLoader), then just use MODS folder for the mods. Also mods themself **do not support any other behaviour** anymore.

That is why you don't need to use WinRAR anymore.

Comment: Don't you need Forge to do this?

Comment: @colorfusion Sure you need Forge. But that has nothing to do with the question. Core mods that needed to be dropped into minecraft.jar are YEARS deprecated O_o

Comment: There are still many mods that you'll need an extractor for (not to drop the files directly into minecraft.jar), though looking into it the two mods that OP has mentioned shouldn't need it. Just thought it'd be worth mentioning that this method requires Forge to be installed, which OP may/may not already have.